# How to get the prams value over the link router in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this link in main component how to get the value in the player component:

```
 <Link to="/player" params={{ testvalue: "hello" }} 
 className="btn">watch</Link>

class Player extends React.Component{
    render(){
        alert(this.params.testvalue);
        return(
            <div></div>
              );
    }
}
```

This is a route file

```
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={main}/>
      <Route path="/player" component={Player}/>
    </Route>
```

Comment: For helping you with this params in the future you can just take a look with the react devtool on chrome and you can all props you have in the Link just a tips

Answer (score 0):

with react router it passes a location object down as props, should be able to access the query using

`this.props.params.testvalue`

in you Player component

Comment: there is no test value query: Object:

Comment: misread the original question. updated answer. Do `this.props.params` should show that `testvalue` is available in there and can do `this.props.params.testvalue`

Comment: digging through sourcecode, params isn't a prop for Link, you should change it to `query={{ testvalue: "hello" }}` and then it will be available in the query

Comment: i found the prob i had to change route     `<Route path="/player/:id" component={Player}/>` after doing that your solution this.props.params.testvalue is working

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are passing a param with

```
 <Link to="/player" params={{ testvalue: "hello" }} 
 className="btn">watch</Link>
```

but you are not receiving it in the Route. Change you route like

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={main}/>
  <Route path="/player/:value" component={Player}/>
</Route>
```

Then use

```
this.props.params.testvalue
```

in your Player component.